# Entity FrameWork : Working with Combox selection ,getting Casting error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-binding, casting

Working On Simple Entity Frame Work sample with Combo Box . i am trying to populate           datagridview on the basis of combo Box selections  but i am getting **casting** error

I have Simple MDF database and i used database first to generate model for EF .
in EF , NiftyFO is a model  consists of  TradId, StrikePrice , VolumeTraded etc ..

```
        NiftyEntities nf = new NiftyEntities();
        NiftyFO nfo = new NiftyFO();

        nfo = (NiftyFO)(comboBox1.SelectedItem);

         var result = from x in nf.NiftyFOes
                     where x.StrikePrice ==nfo.StrikePrice
                     select x;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = result;
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

And the exact error it showing wheni change ComboBox Seletion is

```
 Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType0`1[System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]] 
     to type 'agileLocal.NiftyFO.'
```

and

Combo Box Filled with Strike Price and loaded from the databse throgh the ef and code goes like this

```
             NiftyEntities nf = new NiftyEntities();
          var result2 = from x in nf.NiftyFOes
                          select new { x.StrikePrice };
            //comboBox1.DisplayMember = "StrikePrice";
            comboBox1.DataSource = result2;
```

Solved :

```
select new { x.StrikePrice };
```

i just changed this line

`select x.StrikePrice` . and it worked .

Comment: we should know how did you fill your Combobox, because the problem is in `nfs = (NiftyFO)(comboBox1.SelectedItem);`, and there's no need for `new NiftyFO();`

Comment: Séddik Laraba, i just added method i adopted to load combo box ..please read Post once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

then your code will be

```
   decimal myselected = (decimal)(comboBox1.SelectedItem);


 var result = from x in nf.NiftyFOes
                 where x.StrikePrice == myselected 
                 select x;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = result;
    dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

because in your `select new { x.StrikePrice };` you are selecting the `StrikePrice` and not the object it self

Comment: if StrikePrice  is nullable you can cast to `decimal?`

Comment: Larba  in selected Item it showing like this " { StrikePrice = 4500 } " and getting Specific casting is not valid ,any idea?

Comment: my bad, am sorry, in the `select new { x.StrikePrice };` you created a new object with a single property, the only way is to use `decimal myselected = (decimal)((comboBox1.SelectedItem as dynamic).StrikePrice) ;` but as you changed it to direct selection `select x.StrikePrice;`, no need for this anymore, :-)

Comment: Séddik Laraba , your answer gave me another way to solve this issue thank very much .